How to solve "flight to the moon" problem in Gazebo + Ardupilot?
As soon as I put arm throttle command in the terminal, the copter takes off fast and high.
Advices I encounter suggest to change filter settings (f.e. this), but they refer to Betaflight and actual real drones, while I am interested in a simulation solution.
How do I implement this in Gazebo?

I'm using Gazebo Harmonic 8.6.0 + Ardupilot SITL. The drone is X-frame self-build one.
What I also tried before:

checked up propellers orientation. They rotate as they should one-by-one while motor tests
set up 40% thrust/weight ratio (doesn't matter if it's 50% or 80%) according to motors specifications
PWM is set from 1000 to 2000, multiplier = 15508 according to specs
IMU sensor is OK

